# Possible definition of infinite-dimensional manifold.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, banach-spaces, smooth-manifolds

Upon a quick google search for a definition of an infinite-dimensional manifold, we find that there are some different choices for definitions available. One definition using Banach spaces was discussed on MathOverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121306/how-are-infinite-dimensional-manifolds-most-commonly-treated), for example.

Given that a $d$-dimensional manifold is a Hausdorff space which is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^d = \bigcup_{n=1}^d \mathbb{R}^n $, a n alternative possible definition that came to mind - but that I can't see anywhere - is that an infinite-dimensional manifold is a Hausdorff topological space which is locally homeomorphic to $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{R}^n$.

My question is, is this a definition which has been used anywhere, and if so, where?

On the other hand, is there anything that I'm overlooking which means that this definition doesn't make sense somehow?

Comment: I think you need be extremely careful about what you mean by those unions. I assume you mean that we are identifying $\mathbb{R}^k$ as a sub space of $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$ as a $k$-dimensional hyperplane through the origin?

Comment: Yes, indeed. And for the infinite one, we equip it with the topology induced by realising it as this colimit.

Comment: I don’t think this is going to give you any ordinary realization of an infinite dimensional Euclidean space. In particular, for any $x \in \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{R}^n$, we’re going to have that $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$. In other words, you’re going to be picking out only the sub space of $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ that is zero in all but finitely many coordinates. Is there a natural differential structure to put on such a space? Wouldn’t it be better to work with the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: I see. Regarding your question,  I don't (necessarily) want a differential structure. My perspective is hunting for a definition for an infinite dimensional topological manifold, without insisting on extra structure.

Comment: That makes sense. I guess what I’m trying to suggest is that this isn’t what comes to mind when I think of “infinite dimensional Euclidean space”. I think of a Hilbert space. So if you’re looking for something that is “locally topologically infinite-dimensional Euclidean space”, I would think you would want to be looking at a Hilbert space. That being said, I don’t think there’s any obvious reason you couldn’t define a “manifold” this way.

Comment: @Matt What exactly do you mean by "extra structure"? I assume you're referring to a complete norm that you find in a Banach space. If so, I don't a priori see any issue with choosing any infinite dimensional topological vector space as the model space. Though this feels somewhat less natural to me, as we use $\mathbb{R}^n$ in the finite dimensional case--which has a natural differentiable structure and a topology induced by a complete norm (and indeed a complete inner product).

Comment: "Hunting for a definition" is not actually how mathematical definitions arise. Instead, mathematical definitions arise by abstracting an important and useful concept and slapping a name on it. From this process we have [Banach manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_manifold), [Frechet manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fréchet_manifold), [Hilbert manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_manifold), [Hilbert cube manifolds](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society/volume-76/issue-6/Hilbert-cube-manifolds/bams/1183532416.full),...

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your particular local model, as long as you are not aiming for a class of spaces satisfying the Baire property.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I am very interested in knowing how this definition would result in spaces which violate the Baire property, as opposed to (say) a Hilbert manifold!

Comment: Simple: $R^\infty$ as you defined it is a countable union of nowhere dense closed subsets, hence, fails the Baire property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to define manifolds is a "model" TVS, a [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space) $E$, usually assumed to be Hausdorff. Then you define an $E$-manifold as a Hausdorff topological space which is locally homeomorphic to $E$. Which space (or a class of spaces) $E$ to use, depends on the objective: What are you planning to do with the $E$-manifolds, which properties do you find desirable, etc. Your example of $E= {\mathbb R}^\infty$, equal to the inductive limit of ${\mathbb R}^n$'s, is a perfectly reasonable TVS. However, it is lacking one property that might be desirable for applications, namely, the Baire Property: Each nonempty ${\mathbb R}^\infty$-manifold will contain a sequence of nowhere dense  (closed) subsets whose union has nonempty interior. This is because each ${\mathbb R}^n\subset {\mathbb R}^\infty$ has empty interior, but the union of these finite-dimensional subspaces equals the entire ${\mathbb R}^\infty$.

Edit. I did not see this class of manifolds anywhere in the literature, but, given vastness of the literature on infinite-dimensional spaces, it would not surprise me if somebody did use them for something. On the other hand, lack of the Baire Property suggests that the number of such references is likely to be small.